# File upload in server using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working web form (.aspx) application.
I need to file upload in server using ajax
I can't send file.
any one help me(with details).

```
    var files = $("#bodyContentPlaceHolder_fileProfilePhoto")[0].files[0];
 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "User.aspx/AjaxSaveUser",

                        //contentType: false,

                        data: JSON.stringify({ model: model, inputFile: files }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            AlertMessage(model.UserID, "success");
                            GridDataBind(data);
                            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                        },
```

Comment: Full code not provide.I can post request without files,But when 2nd perimeter is add then request can't post.  how to get value in c#

Answer (score 0):

Javascript client side code:

```
function upload() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
    formData.append("guid", theGuid);
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/myController/Upload',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
      alert('succes!!');
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert("errror");
    }
  });
}
```

on server side:

```
Request.Form["guid"];
Request.Files["FileUpload"];
```

Comment: what is this Request.Form["guid"];

Comment: buddy i lost the above link where i read the article but try this link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/upload-files-through-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: Providing some detail on what your code sample does will help educate. Instead of providing a link to a resource which might not be around at some point in the future, provide a summary of the key points which will help people understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry I have failed. i have used with successfully in mvc project. But failed in web form (.aspx) project.